# How would I get all the values of a field in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 rows with 3 fields, one row is numbers, how do I get all of those numbers? in that field? LIKE mysql_fetch_rows() in a for loop doesn't work?

Comment: Can you actually show us what you tried? Just saying it doesn't work doesn't give us a lot to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

In this code, it was selected a "person" from table "people" that had `id = 42`. Only one row of results is expected so, all that is needed is `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);`.
After this `$row` will be something like this: `array(0 => 42, 1 => 'person@people.xx');`.
To print the email, you access the second position of `$row` by echoing `$row[1]`.

This is exactly what's going on [php documentation about `mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row)

---

On the other hand, if you expect several rows to be returned, from a query like: `SELECT id, email FROM people WHERE email LIKE '%@people%'`, you should use `mysql_fetch_array()` with a `while` loop. You can see example at [`mysql_fetch_array()` documentation](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-array)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get all three numerical values from three different rows in one result you should look into MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)